# How to debug selenium remote web driver running by jbehave stories?

Tags: java, selenium, jbehave, remotewebdriver

I'm running jbehave stories and using selenium with remote chrome driver in it. Debugging is working in Intellij, but app stops running on webdriver methods calling without any breakpoints or errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.